# How can this insert query be optimized?

Tags: sqlite, join, optimization, insert, outer-join

To start off:

> Generally speaking, the EXISTS operator is faster than IN operator if
> the result set returned by the subquery is large. By contrast, the IN
> operator is faster than the EXISTS operator if the result set returned
> by the subquery is small.

that's according to SQLite docs. The list of platform names will never be very large, nor is it likely media_capture_form rows will be. Now the question, how to optimize this?

```
# Called at startup  to  add rows to PLATFORMS table so all rows of the
# MEDIA_CAPTURE_FORM table have a link to every platform. Without this,
# media_capture_form entries won't have platform fields for newly added
# platforms,  causing problems for the newly added platform tabs in the
# UI. This design needs to accommodate a growing list of platforms.
def addPlatform(self, platformName):
    # Add the new platform into platforms and don't allow duplicates.
    # there will always be at least 1 row in media_capture_form table
    # that reresents a blank form.
    sql =  "INSERT INTO platforms (formPky,name,chk,url,date,opt_a,opt_b,opt_c) "
    sql += "SELECT 1,?,'','','','','','' "
    sql +=  "WHERE name not in (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM platforms)"
    self.runCommand(sql, (platformName,))
```

The above for only the first row of media_capture_table, but need to do the same for all others as well. My SQL skills are a bit rusty these days, but my intuition says there's a way to employ joins to do this better. However, there are limited options for outer joins in SQLite, so I'm open to all ideas...

Comment: Post the definitions of the 2 tables.

Comment: The media_capture_form table has 15 columns, the platforms table (as can be seen in the code I posted) has 8 columns. # of rows in tables is small but variable. distinct platform names is less than 30. Not likely more than several hundred rows in media_capture_form table.